# How to properly combine PHP result in this javascript line?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have confirmation alert using [bootbox,js](http://bootboxjs.com/). In the bootbox, user is allowed to make a custom html form. But, I have some of my form element/value that is populated from PHP foreach. I've tried to write like this but it's not working. The alert is not triggered.

```
bootbox.confirm({
        title   : "Testing",
        message : 
        "<form id='test'>\
         <h3>Dept: </h3>\
         <table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3px'>\
         <?php foreach($dept as $row_dept){ ?>
         <tr>\
             <td align='center' width='5%'><input type='checkbox' name='first_name' /></td>\
             <td align='left'>"+<?php $row_dept->dept; ?>+"</td>\ /*If I remove this line, there is no error. But no value is shown*/
         </tr>\
         <?php }; ?>
         <tr>\
             <td colspan='2'><h3>Disposisi</h3>\<textarea id='disposisi' name='disposisi' class='form-control'></textarea></td>\
         </tr>\
         </table>\
         </form>",
        buttons : {
                    cancel  : { label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Batal' },
                    confirm : { label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> OK'}
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if(result == true){
                var disposisi = $("#test").find('textarea[name=disposisi]').val();
                alert(disposisi);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: why you not echoing PHP value?

Comment: @RanaGhosh I tried to replaced the form with something simple like `<?php echo "test"; ?>`. But, it's not working. I think the proble is the `echo`

Comment: is there showing any error in console?

Comment: When I change all the form to `<?php echo "A"; ?>` there is an error. A is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a newline issue.

Try this - the backtick `  works in newer browsers - otherwise use "..."+"..." all the way

```js
bootbox.confirm({
  title: "Testing",
  message: `<form id='test'>
         <h3>Dept: </h3>
         <table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3px'>
         <?php foreach($dept as $row_dept){ ?>
         <tr>
             <td align='center' width='5%'><input type='checkbox' name='first_name' /></td>\
             <td align='left'><?php echo $row_dept->dept; ?></td>
         </tr>
         <?php }; ?>
         <tr>
             <td colspan='2'><h3>Disposisi</h3><textarea id='disposisi' name='disposisi' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
         </tr>
         </table>
         </form>`,
  buttons: {
    cancel: {
      label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Batal'
    },
    confirm: {
      label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> OK'
    }
  },
  callback: function(result) {
    if (result == true) {
      var disposisi = $("#test").find('textarea[name=disposisi]').val();
      alert(disposisi);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried to copy your code and paste it. But, it's not working

Comment: "Not working" is a very useless comment. Any console errors? View the source of the page to see other issues?

Comment: every other PHP code except the one that use `echo` seems ok. Just when I do `echo` the script is error

Comment: When I change all the form to `<?php echo "A"; ?>` there is an error. A is not defined